# Delete value by updating field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, c#-5.0

I have this:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Bycicle</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="BycicleID">Mark</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("BycicleID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id)
            </div>
        </div>
```

The controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Bycicle bycicle = await db.Bycicles.FindAsync(id);
            if (bycicle == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.id = new SelectList(db.Bycicles, "BycicleID", "Mark", bycicle.id);
            //ViewBag.Color = new SelectList(db.Bycicles, "Color", "Color", bycicle.Color);
            //ViewBag.Weight = new SelectList(db.Bycicles, "Weight", "Weight", bycicle.Weight);
            //ViewBag.Height = new SelectList(db.Bycicles, "Height", "Height", bycicle.Height);
            return View(bycicle);
        }

        // POST: Bycicle/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(
           [Bind(Include = "id, Mark, Color, Weight,Height")] 
       Bycicle bycicle)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid )
            {
                db.Entry(bycicle).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


            ViewBag.id = new SelectList(db.Bycicles, "id", "Mark", bycicle.id);


            return View(bycicle);
        }
```

and the Model:

```
public class Bycicle
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        // [Column("Mark")]
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        public string Height { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastTimeChecked { get; set; }


    }
```

But so I can update the other values(Color, Weight, Height) But the Mark name will be deleted if I press save in the Update view. I also checked the db and the Mark value is gone after Update. But If I just press on Edit(update) Then first I see the value(Mark) in the dropdownlist, but after save the mark value is gone. Even if I didnt changed the Mark value in the Update view.

I just cant figure what is wrong.

Thank you!!

Oke,

I did understand it was a type mistake,

But what do you mean with the dropdonlists are not correct? Because you dont have a infinite mark list of bycicles. So that Is why I choose to make a dropdownlist with all the marks and the colors and the sizes. Because an admin fill in the marks, sizes, etc and then the user can select a mark, color, etc. But how will you design the different properties?

I dont have seperate tables for color, mark, etc. But is that necessary?

Thank you

Comment: So if there are no `Bycicle` created yet, then `new SelectList(db.Bycicles, "Color", "Color", bycicle.Color);` will be null - i.e. you can never select a colour. Of course you need separate tables for colours with a foreign key relationship to `Bycicle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not binding anything to the property `Mark` (what you have shown is bound to the `ID` property). Preferably the names of your select lists should not be the same as your properties.

In the controller

```
ViewBag.MarkList = new SelectList(db.Bycicles, "BycicleID", "Mark");
```

and in the view

```
@model YourAssembly.Bycicle
....
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mark)
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Mark, (SelectList)ViewBag.MarkList)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Mark)
  </div>
</div>
```

Note, since you binding all properties, you do not need `[Bind(Include = "id, Mark, Color, Weight,Height")]`

**Edit**

While passing values by `ViewBag` works, I recommend you use view models and strongly typed helpers so you have intellisense support as well as all the other benefits of using view models.

```
public class BycicleVM
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  // other properties of Bycicle that you want to edit
  public SelectList MarkList { get; set; }
  // other select lists
}
```

then assign the select lists to the view model rather than ViewBag

Comment: Note also I don't think your select lists make sense since your binding them all to `db.Bycicles`. Do you have tables for `BycicleMarks`, `BycicleColours` etc?

Comment: You have attempted to edit my answer which will be rejected (add comments or edit your question instead). Note my update (spelling mistake `ViewBag.MakeList` should be `ViewBag.MarkList`)